# Setting up cron job in google app engine python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cron

I'm just getting started with Google App Engine so I'm still learning how to configure everything. I wrote a script called parsexml.py that I want to run every 10 minutes or so. This file is in my main directory, alongside main.py, app.yaml, etc. As I understand it, I need to create a new file, cron.yaml which looks like this:

```
cron:
- description: scrape xml
  url: /
  schedule: every 10 minutes
```

I'm not sure what I need to put in the url field. I'm also not sure if anything else is needed. Do I need to change my app.yaml file at all? Where do I specify the name of my parsexml.py file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Brian,

You'll need to update both your `app.yaml` and `cron.yaml` files. In each of these, you'll need to specify the path where the script will run.

`app.yaml`:

```
handlers:
- url: /path/to/cron
  script: parsexml.py
```

or if you have a catch all handler you won't need to change it. For example:

```
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: parsexml.py
```

`cron.yaml`:

```
cron:
- description: scrape xml
  url: /path/to/cron
  schedule: every 10 minutes
```

As in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/running), in `parsexml.py` you'll need to specify a handler for `/path/to/cron` and register it with a WSGI handler (or you could use CGI):

```
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class ParseXMLHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # do something

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/path/to/cron', ParseXMLHandler)],
                                     debug=True)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_wsgi_app(application)
```

**Note**: If you are using the Python 2.7 runtime, you will want to specify `script: parsexml.application` where `application` is a global WSGI variable for handling requests.

Comment: This would also work fine if he added the cron handler to his existing WSGI app - in which case app.yaml would likely not need modifying.

Answer (score 2):

In GAE, all actions are done via URLs. You can't just run an arbitrary script as a cron: you need to make that script a handler and give it a URL, like any other view in your project.

So, map a URL to your script in app.yaml, edit the script to make it a handler, and use that URL in cron.yaml.

Comment: descriptive answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The url is used to run the py script for your cron job

basically in your app.yaml

you have

```
app.yaml
handlers:
- url: /helloworld.py
  script: helloworld.py
```

in cron.yaml

```
cron.yaml
- description: scrape xml
  url: /helloworld.py
  schedule: every 10 minutes
```

if you want the cron to run hello world you have to set the url as `url: /helloworld.py`

Comment: So I would put "url:/parsexml.py"  ?

Comment: if that is the url in your app.yaml