# Unsure how to configure WSGI handler/Flask to enable cron job in Python/App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, cron

I have the following code which works successfully when I deploy it on App Engine. Except I want to run it with a cron.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def sfLibraries():
    return 'Success'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: "SF Loader"
  url: /task/loader
  schedule: every 1 hours
```

app.yaml

```
runtime: python38

handlers:

- url: /task/loader
  script: auto
```

I know that if I change @app.route('/') to @app.route('/task/loader') that the cron will work successfully, yet I lose the capability to go to the site when I first deploy it and see success.

```
gcloud app browse
Did not detect your browser. Go to this link to view your app:
https://<<<my_synapse>>>.uc.r.appspot.com
```

https://<<<my_synapse>>>.uc.r.appspot.com:

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
```

How can I have it both ways -both able to go to the site via gcloud app browse and see success as well as run the cron successfully?

I mentioned WSGI Handler because I found this pertinent post but not sure how WSGI Handler might help or improve from what Flask is doing [Setting up cron job in google app engine python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399313/setting-up-cron-job-in-google-app-engine-python)

Answer (score 1):

Create two different routes to accomplish what you need. The functions must have a different name in this case.

```py
@app.route('/')
def sfLibraries():
    return 'Success'

@app.route('/task/loader')
def sfLibrariesSecond():
    return 'Success'
```

Assign different actions for each one.

They could also both do the exact same thing. If that was the case, then assign two routes to the same function.

```py
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/task/loader')
def sfLibraries():
    return 'Success'
```